# how to remove white space in select 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I had dynamically added the value of the option in select2 as it came from the database but when the field has no value the space can be selected.

How should I remove the spaces? I tried this codes but nothing happens

```
$imei = $row["IMEI_MX"];
$imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);

<select id="tags"
    name="imei"
    class="form-control"
    onchange="getCount()"
    multiple
    disabled
>
foreach ($imeiserial as $imeiserial) {
    $wew = ltrim($imeiserial, " \t.");
    echo '<option value=' . $imei . '>' . $wew . '</option>';
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5wlO.png)

Comment: Example content of your $row["IMEI_MX"]?

Comment: 867637026628082, 867637026628090

Comment: but if the imei_mx is empty its still appearing the spaces

Comment: Just add one if case check $row["IMEI_MX"] Null or Not Null.

Comment: `field have no value the space can be selected` what does this mean?

Comment: spaces that can be selected

Comment: One thing I notice: in the `foreach($a as $b)` statement, `$a` and `$b` should be different. You have `$imeiserial` in both positions, which may cause problems. `$a` should be an array, while `$b` is a single item from the array, used only in the current iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your general layout is, but if you're using PHP to generate the HTML `select` tag, then you can try something like this:

```
$imei = $row["IMEI_MX"];
$imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);

echo '<select id="tags" name="imei" disabled class="form-control" onchange="getCount()" multiple>';

foreach($imeiserial as $is){
    $wew = trim($is);

    if (!empty($wew)) {
        echo "<option value='$wew'>$wew</option>";
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

The [PHP empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function will return `true` if the variable is NULL, an empty string, or does not exist. This means that if the value is a space (or empty string once the [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function has gone through, then it won't output a html `<option>` tag.

This is all assuming that you're meant to be creating a separate `<option>` for each element in the array after an explode (I'm guessing it's a comma-separated list of IMEIs) but you were outputting the entire string as the value rather than just the element.

e.g.

```
<option value='867637026628082, 867637026628090'>867637026628082</option>
```

rather than

```
<option value='867637026628082'>867637026628082</option>
```